# How to vertically format embedded fields

Tags: c#, discord, bots, discord.net

[Current Formatting For Embed Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfCNL.jpg)

Here is an embed I currently use for my semi-public Ark Servers.
First field is the Map name,
Second field is the direct connect IP Address,
Third field is if/where there is a community base on that map.
As you can see it works as intended but if there's to much info on a single line in the field the formatting is screwed up. Is there a way to fix this?
I'm using 3 separate stream builders to build the different fields and then adding them to the embed. If code is needed I can post a "dumbed down version" so it doesn't take up the whole page.

```
        var linkHeading = "steam://connect/";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        var sb3 = new StringBuilder();
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        embed.WithColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
        embed.Title = "List of Server Ips";
        JObject o1;
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("serverips.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            o1 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        }

        var ipsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(o1.ToString());

        sb.AppendLine("The Island: ");
        sb2.AppendLine($"{linkHeading}{ipsObject.TheIsland.ip}:{ipsObject.TheIsland.port}/");
        if(ipsObject.TheIsland.comm != "")
        {
            sb3.AppendLine($"Comm: {ipsObject.TheIsland.comm}");
        } else { sb3.AppendLine($"No Comm Info Available"); };
        sb.AppendLine("Aberration: ");
        sb2.AppendLine($"{linkHeading}{ipsObject.Aberration.ip}:{ipsObject.Aberration.port}/");
        if (ipsObject.Aberration.comm != "")
        {
            sb3.AppendLine($"Comm: {ipsObject.Aberration.comm}");
        } else { sb3.AppendLine($"No Comm Info Available"); };
        embed.WithDescription($"Cluster Ip and Comm Information");
        embed.AddField(x =>
        {
            x.Name = "Map";
            x.Value = sb.ToString();
            x.IsInline = true;
        });
        embed.AddField(x =>
        {
            x.Name = "IP";
            x.Value = sb2.ToString();
            x.IsInline = true;
        });
        embed.AddField(x =>
        {
            x.Name = "Comm?";
            x.Value = sb3.ToString();
            x.IsInline = true;
        });

        await Context.User.SendMessageAsync(null, false, embed.Build());
        await ReplyAsync("Server Ip List was sent directly to your inbox! :)");
```

Comment: I don't know discord, but I expect that code would be necessary, yes. Please provide an [mre].

Comment: First post so getting used to the formatting. Code is posted in the Answer section.
This is only the first couple lines of the string builders so it's a shortened version.

Comment: Please delete the answer and [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: I did originally, it was to long to put in a comment.

Comment: Perhaps you're not reading my comment correctly. [Edit] your question. Click the [edit] link I keep putting in my comments. There is also an [edit] link under the question. That will put the *question* in edit mode. You can then paste the code in that. The code belongs in the question, not as an answer to the question, because that make no sense.

Comment: Ah that's a my bad! There wasn't an edit button up there originally!

Comment: Can't you simply make the window wider so lines don't wrap? (don't know Discord, so don't know how to do that)

Comment: No, I looked into that as well. From what I found it's a set width of device. I will dig deeper into it though.
**EDIT:**
Sounds like you can just make the footer insanely wide. I will try this.

**EDIT2:**
This did not work. Footer just runs off the side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have that much control over how embed fields are displayed. The only thing you control in regards to fields are if they `inline` or not. The rendering is completely up to Discord and the end users screen size. For example, your current output on mobile will ignore the `inline` setting and list the fields one on top of the other instead of side by side.

Unless your fields consistently contain a small amount of text each you can't guarantee how the end use will see the output. If you need to guarantee some sort of consistent structured display across all devices, your best bet is to use an image.

Comment: That's what I wasn't hoping to hear but it further backs up my research! Thank you

Comment: I ended up just sending a message to the command user with a StringBuilder instead of putting into an embed. My users liked this flow a bit better as it was easily readable.
I also thought about in the future checking if string length is greater than x or something similar to add a second line to any column that would otherwise styled incorrectly. This seems to out of place though and inconsistent so I dropped the idea.